# Cómo hacer para que la modificación de un diccionario se guarde para futuros usos del programa?

Tags: python

estoy tratando de hacer un login en el que te puedas registrar, pero quiero que al registrarse se guarde en el diccionario para futuras sesiones y no puedo.
este es el codigo
la primera parte es una calculadora a la cual se accedería despues de acceder con usuario y contraseña (no subí esa parte), y despues es para acceder que es lo que sí subí

```
import getpass
users = {
  "gabito":{
      "psswd":"gabss"
  },
  "vanerr":{
      "psswd":"val895"
  },
  "serfs":{
      "psswd":"ser422"
  }
 }   

 def logon():
   chose=input("Do you want to logon: Yes / No: ")
   if chose == "yes":
      username=input("Username: ")
      password1=getpass.getpass("Password: ")
      password2=getpass.getpass("Repeat password: ")
      if password1==password2:
         users[username] = {"psswd":password1}
         print("User log in succesfully!")
         access()
      else:
         print("Password are not the same!")
          logon()
  elif chose =="no":
      access()

  def access(): 
   us= input("Username:")
   if us in users:
     def psswd():
       pss=getpass.getpass("Password:")
       if pss == users[us]["psswd"]:
         calcu()
      else:
        print("Password wrong!") 
        access()
   psswd()
  else:
     print("User not found!")
     logon ()

 access()
```

Comment: El programa no tiene mucho sentido. Definir una función dentro de un `if`, que a su vez está dentro de otra función y luego es llamada fuera del `if`, o sea que si no se cumple la condición va a tirar error... Por otro lado la indentación no es consistente, no se deben mezclar diferente espaciado en las sentencias. El [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) recomienda 4 espacios por nivel. Cuando dices que el diccionario se guarde para futuras sesiones, ¿es mientras dure la ejecución del script o permanentemente?

Comment: Para hacer los datos persistentes necesitas algun almacenamiento, podria ser un archivo o una base de datos, esta dentro de lo que planeas hacer?

Comment: Gracias por contestar, primero defino una función dentro del if para poder volver a llamarla, había pensado en usar un bucle pero no sé me ocurrió como. Si no se cumple la condición no me tira error, lo que pasa es que es la primera vez que uso stack overflow y me decía de identar para adjuntarlo como código, a lo mejor quedó medio mal cuando lo hice.

Comment: Cuando digo que se guarde para futuras sesiones, me refiero se forma permanente, ya que sí funciona bien durante la ejecución del script,

Comment: Cómo podría almacenarlo en un archivo o base de datos? Solo lo estoy haciendo para aprender, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes guardar el diccionario en un archivo usando json, que es un formato de intercambio ampliamente utilizado.

Si tienes un diccionario, usas la función `json.dumps(diccionario)` para convertirlo en su representación json. Formalmente, la función produce un string que luego grabas en un archivo.

Para recuperar el diccionario, tienes que leer el string desde el archivo, y usar la función `json.loads(string)` para obtener de vuelta el diccionario original.

Esto queda mejor expresado con este programa de prueba:

```
import json

users = {
  "gabito":{
      "psswd":"gabss"
  },
  "vanerr":{
      "psswd":"val895"
  },
  "serfs":{
      "psswd":"ser422"
  }
 }
```

Primero, convertir el diccionario a un string

```
dic_json = json.dumps(users)
```

Luego grabamos el string en un archivo en disco:

```
with open("test.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(dic_json)
```

Más tarde, queremos recuperar el diccionario. Entonces leemos del archivo y deshacemos la operación anterior:

```
with open("test.json", "r") as json_file:
    dic_json = json_file.readline()
    users = json.loads(dic_json)
```

y con eso, `users` vuelve a tener su contenido original.

**Comprobación**

```
import json

users = {
  "gabito":{
      "psswd":"gabss"
  },
  "vanerr":{
      "psswd":"val895"
  },
  "serfs":{
      "psswd":"ser422"
  }
 }

dic_json = json.dumps(users)

with open("test.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(dic_json)

dic_json = None
users = None
with open("test.json", "r") as json_file:
    dic_json = json_file.readline()
    users = json.loads(dic_json)

print(users)
```

Produce:

```
{'gabito': {'psswd': 'gabss'}, 'vanerr': {'psswd': 'val895'}, 'serfs': {'psswd': 'ser422'}}
```

Comment: Ahh entiendo entiendo, voy a probar, gracias a todos

Answer (score 1):

Para que el usuario quede registrado permanentemente debes hacerlo en una base de datos, un archivo o alguna otra opción.

Te voy a proponer un modelo muy básico de cómo podrías registrar y almacenar a los usuarios usando un archivo de texto en formato JSON, el cual se escribirá en el mismo directorio que el script de python. [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) es la estructura de datos que correspondería de forma natural un diccionario de Python, por lo que es muy fácil convertir de uno a otro.

```
import os, json

users = {}

def read_json():
    global users
    if not os.path.isfile('users.json'):
        # Si no existe el archivo, crear uno nuevo con valores default
        write_json({'admin' : {'psswd' : 'admin'}})
    with open('users.json') as json_data:
        users = json.load(json_data,)
    
def write_json(data):
    with open('users.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file)
        
def input_user():
    username = input("Nombre de usuario: ").lower()
    password = input("Contraseña de usuario: ")
    return username, password
    
def new_user():
    print("\nREGISTRAR USUARIO")
    global users
    username, password = input_user()
    if not username in users:
        users[username] = {'psswd' : password}
        write_json(users) # Guardar en el archivo JSON
        print("Usuario registrado correctamente")
    else:
        print("Error, el usuario ya existe")
    
def logon():
    print("\nINICIA SESION")
    global users
    username, password = input_user()
    login = False
    if username in users:
        if users[username]['psswd'] == password:
            login = True
        else:
            print("El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos")
    else:
        print("El usuario no está registrado")
    return login
```

Puedes usar ese formato para seguir el código restante, o crear un menú para llamar las distintas opciones, tu dirás.

Una prueba de la ejecución podría ser:

```
# ###################
read_json() # Cargar el diccionario con los datos del archivo json
logon()
new_user()
if(logon()):
    print(" ** Aqui el resto del programa **")
```

Salida

> ```
> INICIA SESION
> Nombre de usuario: gabito
> Contraseña de usuario: gabss
> El usuario no está registrado
>
> REGISTRAR USUARIO
> Nombre de usuario: gabito
> Contraseña de usuario: gabss
> Usuario registrado correctamente
>
> INICIA SESION
> Nombre de usuario: gabito
> Contraseña de usuario: gabss
>  ** Aqui el resto del programa **
> ```